# Mongo DB: How to get original Document after aggregation stage $group?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Documents that I have:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "entity": "Category",
    "property": "name",
    "changed": "2021-08-30"
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "entity": "Category",
    "property": "name",
    "changed": "2020-08-31"
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "entity": "Category",
    "property": "description",
    "changed": "2020-08-29"
  },
  {
    "_id": 4,
    "entity": "Category",
    "property": "description",
    "changed": "2020-08-30"
  },
  {
    "_id": 5,
    "entity": "Category",
    "property": "description",
    "changed": "2020-08-31"
  }
]
```

I am trying to execute the following query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        property: "$property"
      },
      lastChanged: {
        $max: "$changed"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

to find the Documents per each unique property that was last modified

The query output is:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "property": "name"
    },
    "lastChanged": "2021-08-30"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "property": "description"
    },
    "lastChanged": "2020-08-31"
  }
]
```

The problem that I have, it is how to return original Documents not just some custom query output?

Answer (score 4):

Use this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $group: {
         _id: { property: "$property" },
         lastChanged: { $max: "$changed" },
         data: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         data: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$data",
               cond: { $eq: ["$$this.changed", "$lastChanged"] }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

Then in your result you have a field `data` with all your documents.

Comment: I do not need all my documents, I need documents with max changed date per property.

Comment: You can apply a `$filter` afterwards, see my update.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve using sort

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $sort: {
      changed: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        property: "$property"
      },
      data: {
        $first: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5BA9wliPFJU)

Comment: the requirement that I have is to use $max operator.

Comment: This does not work if you have more than just one document matching the `lastChanged` value

Comment: so at that time you need all documents which are matched?

Comment: The question states: "how to return original document_**s**"

Comment: Ohh, fine, I was confused because of the duplication of given sample data. Then you can go  with `$filter` as @WernfriedDomscheit answered